# Python Pandas to_csv getting extra rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to merge two csv files on top of each other that may have different column headers. Problem I'm having is it seems to be splitting to a new line randomly.

```
File 1:
ID, Height
0 , 1
1 , 2
2 , 3

File 2:

ID, Message
0 , "Long string message"
1 , "May include tabs, multiple lines \n
     that go on for a while"
2 , "More of the same"
```

Result Should Be:

```
ID, Height, Message
0,    1,     '',
1,    2,     '',
2,    3,     '',
0,    '',    "Long string message",
1,    '',    "May include tabs, multiple lines \n
              that go on for a while",
2,    '',    "More of the same"
```

What I'm getting back is:

```
ID, Height, Message
0,    1,     '',
1,    2,     '',
2,    3,     '',
0,    '',    "Long string message",
1,    '',    "May include tabs, multiple lines"
"that go on for a while", '', '',
2,    '',    "More of the same"
```

I'm getting it to work for the most part with the following:

```
first = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
second = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

merged = pd.concat([first, second], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
merged.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Looks like if there is an extra line in the message field, it splits to a new line. How Can I stop it from delimiting based upon a new line in the message field?

Comment: It would be helpful if you also post the result you are currently seeing.

Comment: @sgrg updated my output i'm currently seeing

Comment: Does the data really break line like that in *File 2*?

Comment: @parfait well, I'm assuming it's breaking line because in the csv file I see that the cell is broke out into multiple lines with an empty line in between them

Comment: Can you open csv in a text editor (like Notepad not Excel) and add it to your post?

Answer (score 1):

From the short example you gave it looks like it is starting a new row on the new line character `\n`

you could try using  `first = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', delim_whitespace = True)`

try changing the `separator`, `lineterminator`, or delimiter-like parameters in `read_csv` [here.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)